# Hibernate 5.2.9.Final cache not updated

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I have a service (which I for some reason call controller) that is injected into the Jersey resource method.

```
@Named
@Transactional
public class DocCtrl {
   ...

public void changeDocState(List<String> uuids, EDocState state, String shreddingCode) throws DatabaseException, WebserviceException, RepositoryException, ExtensionException, LockException, AccessDeniedException, PathNotFoundException, UnknowException {
        List<Document2> documents = doc2DAO.getManyByUUIDs(uuids);
        for (Document2 doc : documents) {
            if (EDocState.SOFT_DEL == state) {
                computeShreddingFor(doc, shreddingCode); //here the state change happens and it is persisted to db
            }

            if (EDocState.ACTIVE == state)
                unscheduleShredding(doc);
        }
    }
}
```

`doc2DAO.getManyByUUIDs(uuids);` gets an Entity object from the database.

```
@Repository
public class Doc2DAO {
@PersistenceContext(name = Vedantas.PU_NAME, type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    private EntityManager entityManager;

public List<Document2> getManyByUUIDs(List<String> uuids) {
        if (uuids.isEmpty())
            uuids.add("-3");

        TypedQuery<Document2> query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("getManyByUUIDs", Document2.class);
        query.setParameter("uuids", uuids);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

However When I do second request to my API, I see state of this entity object unchanged, that means the same as before the logic above occoured.
In DB there is still changed status.
After the api service restart, I will get the entity in the correct state.

As I understand it, Hibernate uses it's L2 cache for the managed objects.
So can you, please point me to what I am doing wrong here? Obviously, I need to get cached entity with the changed state without service restart and I would like to keep entities attached to the persistence context for the performance reasons.

Now, can you tell me what I am 
In the logic I am making some changes to this object. After the completition of the `changeDocState` method, the state is properly changed and persisted in the database.

Thanks for the answers;

Comment: Can you please post the code where you get the object? Not only the DAO but the Controller.

Comment: you have it there

Comment: Ah I see! Why do you have set PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED?

Comment: I am getting IllegalStateException: The associated entity manager is closed! exception with TRANSACTION type ctx. 
Practically what happend to me is sumarized in this article:
https://techblog.bozho.net/spring-and-persistencecontexttype-extended/
I think I have some serious architectural problems here. Or do you have an easy solution/ advice? :)

Comment: where od you get that?

Comment: this is a backend for some GUI app from where Im making parell requests to read some codetables and other entities. this requests span through multiple controllers annotated with @Transactional. I don't know why it's closing it or rather why it doesn't reopen automagically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163059/discussion-between-greengold-and-simon-martinelli).